# When were non-capturing parentheses added to Perl's regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

I am having a hard time figuring out the earliest version of `perl` where non-capturing parentheses are supported in regex patterns?

Can I take this feature for granted for all versions of Perl5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I dug out Perl 5.000 from my archive CDs.  It includes

> `=item (?:regexp)`
>      This groups things like "`()`" but doesn't make backrefences like "`()`" does.

So it's in all versions of Perl 5.  (It's definitely not in Perl 4 or earlier.)

Comment: I am impressed and amazed and disturbed that you had an archived CD with Perl 5.000 ;-)

Comment: For extra disturbance, it was the OS/2 port, as that's what I was using back then. :-)

Comment: FYI, the typo you corrected wasn't mine.  In 5.000, `perlre.pod` had "backrefences" in that sentence.

Comment: @cjm Reinserted the typo for historical accuracy.

Comment: @Sinan: the history isn't secret and is available online http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html

Comment: @Dummy00001 I was not able to locate a mention of when non-capturing parentheses added in any of the deltas, hence the question "Can I take this feature for granted for all versions of Perl5?"

Answer (score 6):

Some time before 5.003_07 according to [perlre](http://search.cpan.org/~andyd/perl5.003_07/pod/perlre.pod) for that version.

Comment: Thank you. No wonder I could not find it in `perldelta` files.

Comment: It would be better saying about RTFM, and add simple explanation. (?:pcre) is enough for that.